# Involved or involve?

Tags: tense

I sent my girl a message:

> If I didn't want to be involved then I wouldn't have.

Then she corrected me by saying I should've used "involve" instead of "involved". I believe I used the correct tense here. What would be the appropriate tense and why?

### Context

Others have been asking about context so here it is, we were talking about my previous relationship before her. It was a very complicated one and I was telling her that I was aware of the difficulties. I was telling her that I got myself into that situation on my own volition. I got involved because I wanted to. If I didn't want to be involved then I wouldn't have.

Comment: Your verbs don't match. "If I didn't want to be involved then I wouldn't be [involved]" OR "If I hadn't wanted to get involved then I wouldn't have."

Comment: @KateBunting: Not a particularly noticeable "mismatch" to me. I just transparently assume ***be*** is short for ***become***, so the utterance can end with elided *...then I wouldn't have [**become involved**].*

Comment: What's the sentence you were told to use? "If I didn't want to be involve then I wouldn't have." is clearly wrong. Normally "involve" is transitive if used in the active, so you'd need to provide an object after "involve", but "be involve" doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @StuartF I was informed of a rule that when you use "did", the following verb must be in the present tense - i.e.: "I didn't go..." instead of "I didn't went..." but yes, to answer your question she told me I should've said "If I didn't want to be involve then I wouldn't have."

Answer (score 2):

"Involved" is the correct adjectival form of the verb "involve".

So:

- I am involved.
- I want to be involved.
- I didn't want to be involved.

"Involve" is definitely wrong.

A grammar purist might argue that if there isn't a context establishing what you wouldn't have done then you might be better adding some extra words, but to an English native speaker what you wrote is fine and will be well understood.

Comment: I added some context in the question.

Answer (score 1):

All by itself, with no other context, your sentence does not work (and neither does her correction, which also would not be grammatical).

The important question that is unanswered here is "you wouldn't have" *what*? Wouldn't have "got involved"? Wouldn't have "Brought you a dozen roses for Valentine's Day"?

If there was a previous sentence that set this one up, then this one could make perfect sense:

Your girl: *"Why did you bring me a dozen roses? I thought you didn't want to get involved."*

You: *"If I didn't want to be involved then I wouldn't have."*

That would be grammatical and make sense, and also be a nice thing to say on Valentine's Day.

But if the reference you're making is to "being involved", then you could just say: "If I didn't want to be involved then I wouldn't have *been*."

Kate's answers in the comments are also appropriate alternatives in this case.

Comment: I added context in the question.

Comment: @dokgu as a pair of sentences this sounds fine to me “I got involved because I wanted to. If I didn't want to be involved then I wouldn't have.”